# Is $\partial_\alpha f^\alpha$ coordinate-independent?

Tags: gravity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, vector-fields, covariance

At [this](https://youtu.be/IBlCu1zgD4Y?list=PLFeEvEPtX_0S6vxxiiNPrJbLu9aK1UVC_&t=2988) point in Schuller's 9th lecture on GR, he claims that Poisson's equation for the Newtonian gravitational field strength is $$-\partial_\alpha f^\alpha=4\pi G \rho,$$
where $\alpha=1,2,3$. But this equation is [usually](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_law_for_gravity#Differential_form) written as $$\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{g} = -4\pi G\rho.$$

I can see that $\partial_\alpha f^\alpha$ and $\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{f}$ are identical in Cartesian coordinates, but the divergence in spherical coordinates (and others) is more certainly complicated than just $\partial_\alpha f^\alpha$. So what justifies Schuller's assertion that the above truly is Poisson's equation in a coordinate-independent setting?

Answer (score 5):

The divergence defined in terms of the covariant derivative,
$$\nabla_i f^i $$
is indeed coordinate independent; that's the whole point of a covariant derivative. However, as you said, the divergence is *not* just equal to $\partial_i\, f^i$ in general. You can relate the two either by expanding out the covariant derivative,
$$\nabla_i\, f^i = \partial_i\, f^i + \Gamma^i_{ji}\, f^j$$ 
or by the formula
$$\nabla_i\, f^i = \frac{1}{\sqrt{g}} \partial_i \left(\sqrt{g} f^i\right).$$
Schuller is probably working in a special coordinate system or class of coordinate systems where these extra terms vanish, for simplicity.

Comment: The second one is not the same as the first one, they are only identical for vanishing torsion and non-metricity. In metric-affine spaces, $\Gamma_{ji}^i$  and $g_{ij}$ are independent variables, in affine spaces there is no agreed/pre-defined metric.

Comment: @OktayDoğangün True, but I'm answering in the context of a standard GR course.

Comment: Maybe it would be better if you specify this as a disclaimer, in order to allow an open window for further concepts. Or it's my selective perception on the topic

Answer (score 3):

1. A major point of [Schuller's 9th lecture](https://youtu.be/IBlCu1zgD4Y?t=00m01s) is that *Newtonian spacetime is curved* from a certain perspective. In fact that's the very title of the lecture.
2. At [14:15](https://youtu.be/IBlCu1zgD4Y?t=14m15s) he introduces a truncated 3-acceleration
   $$ \ddot{x}^{\alpha}+\sum_{\beta, \gamma=1}^3\Gamma^{\alpha}{}_{\beta\gamma}\dot{x}^{\beta}\dot{x}^{\gamma}~=~\ddot{x}^{\alpha}, \qquad \alpha ~\in~\{1,2,3\}, $$
   thereby implicitly implying that all the spatial gamma symbols $\Gamma^{\alpha}{}_{\beta\gamma}=0$ are zero. At this point he is very brief:

   > "This is not the acceleration, but let's not talk about it right now. That comes later."
3. Just before the [46 minute mark](https://youtu.be/IBlCu1zgD4Y?t=46m00s) he identifies the specific force with 3 gamma symbols $$f^{\alpha} ~=~ -\Gamma^{\alpha}{}_{00}, \qquad \alpha ~\in~\{1,2,3\},$$ and he deduces that all the other gamma symbol components should vanish in order for Newton's 2nd law to take the form of the [geodesic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesics_in_general_relativity) in the 4-dimensional spacetime.
4. So yes, the missing term $\sum_{\beta=1}^3\Gamma^{\beta}{}_{\alpha\beta}$ in the spatial 3-divergence formula 
   $$\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{f} ~=~\sum_{\alpha=1}^3\nabla_{\alpha} f^{\alpha}~=~\sum_{\alpha=1}^3\left(\partial_{\alpha}+ \sum_{\beta=1}^3\Gamma^{\beta}{}_{\alpha\beta}\right) f^{\alpha}$$
   is here assumed zero.

Comment: [Another Phys.SE question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/396859/2451) about the 9th lecture.